# How to deploy application on Vercel using MongoDB, Nodejs, ExpressJs, and EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, deployment, vercel

This is what my folder structure looks like:

```
-backend
 -model
 -node_modules
 .env
 app2.js
 index.js
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 vercel.json
-frontend
 -assets
 -public
 -views
```

My frontend is entirely EJS and CSS. I haven't used React anywhere.

**app2.js** contains all the backend logic in a single file and **index.js** has the mongodb configuration

-->index.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  // createIndexes: true 
}).then(() => {
  console.log(`Connection Successful`);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(`Not connected`);
  console.error(e);
});
```

-->vercel.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

After deploying to vercel I'm getting the error 404 not found. I'm confused as to how to deploy to vercel, no youtube video or article has been helpful. Please help me.